# Problems with tiny_mce skins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, tinymce, skin

i having this controller for my blogs and im using tiny_mce there.

my app consists of clans, which belongs_to clandesigns, this clandesigns have a column clandesign.tinymce_skin
blogs belong_to clan

http://pastie.org/1599354

my problem is, even i use the setting in this controller: current_user.nick, i only get:

```
//<![CDATA[
tinyMCE.init({
editor_selector : 'mceEditor',
language : 'en',
mode : 'textareas',
plugins : "spellchecker,pagebreak,layer,table,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
skin : '{current_user.nick}',
spellchecker_rpc_url : '/blogs/spellchecker',
theme : 'advanced',
theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
theme_advanced_buttons2 : "search,replace,bullist,numlist,outdent,indent,blockquote,undo,redo,link,unlink,image,cleanup,preview,forecolor,backcolor",
theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,hr,removeformat,visualaid,sub,sup,charmap,iespell,media,advhr",
theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,styleprops,spellchecker",
theme_advanced_resizing : true,
theme_advanced_statusbar_location : 'bottom',
theme_advanced_toolbar_align : 'left',
theme_advanced_toolbar_location : 'top'

});
//]]>
```

**skin : '{current_user.nick}'**

it feels like i tried every combination of #{}, ", ', : and there are 2 options, i get an indefined method error or tiny_mce just loads the string as skin name

maybe someone can help/give me the code to replace current_user.nick . in the end i wanna have there something like find_clan.clandesign.tinymce_skin

Answer (score 1):

You may want to place your skin under `/tiny_mce/themes/my_custom_skin` and adress it using `theme: "my_custom_skin",`.

Comment: ya thats working , the problem is, forgot to mention it in my first post. blogs is nested behind clans. so i want to access a skin, which name is stored in the clandesigns table and belongs to a specific design

Comment: sry, in that case i do not know if this is possible